# Comprehensive IoC (Inversion of Control) project example

Tags: inversion-of-control

All the articles and papers about this subject, provide overly simplistic examples. The concepts are easy to understand. However, without substantial experience (both myself and my teammates) in this subject, it is not trivial to map the concepts to actual design decisions in a real life system. No way to validate my architecture.

Can anyone provide me with a real system implementation, that correctly implements IoC.

Note: I am not talking about dependency injection. I'm currently using a container, and I use system wide injection. I am more interested in the way code is kept decoupled, i.e., how is library separation performed (to what extent), and how and where is the interface/contract code declared and included.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The open-source GlassFish application server (https://glassfish.java.net/) uses hk2 (https://hk2.java.net) as a DI container.  It has several areas where implementations are kept separate from contracts, and where in fact implementations of those contracts can be dynamically added or removed while the server is up and running.

For example take a look at the command-line (asadmin) facility.  Users can deploy OSGi bundles that can add new implementations of the command-line contract which will then dynamically be added to the set of things asadmin can do.  This is a good example of how to use IoC in order to keep your contracts and services separated.

It is also instructive in that GlassFish was not originally designed with a DI container, so it is a good real-world use case for how to add DI/IoC into systems that were not originally designed in that way.